# Android can't find email client (no application can perform this action)

Tags: android-intent, email-client

I have read the other posts about the error message mentioned above, but since the one I described my still existing problem in has already been marked as answer quite some time ago, I though I should better ask in a separate thread - as none of the tips to resolve the problem have worked for me.
The problem appears when running the app on the phone. K9 Mail and Google Mail are both installed and set up.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    final Intent imail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    imail.setType("message/rfc822"); // or: text/plain
    imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"contact@mydomain.com"});
    imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
    imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , emailText);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(imail, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Feedback.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The app displays the "No application can perform this action" error on the phone.

There is also an another variation I tried without success:

```
    String mailId = (String) "contact@mydomain.com"; 
    final Intent imail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts( 
    "mailto",mailId, null)); 
    imail.setType("message/rfc822"); // text/plain
    imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
    imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);

    // Check if Intent available
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            imail, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

In this case, List returns a size of Null, despite K9 Mail and Google Mail being installed as mentioned above. My System is a HTC One V (Android 4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private void enviar(String[] to, String[] cc, String asunto, String mensaje)
{ 
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, asunto);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email "));
```

}

This works with Gmail